# Flutter setState() doesn't assign value with showDatePicker()

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a a *datepicker* that its value (date) is going to be use for filtering a list. The `datePicker` is contained in a `modalSheet`, I set the date from `_PickedTgl` to `dateteks` but it wont change the value.

Please anyone can explain the best approach for this problem and show me how to do it.
Thank you.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Takok extends StatefulWidget {
  const Takok({super.key});

  @override
  State<Takok> createState() => _TakokState();
}

class _TakokState extends State<Takok> {
  String dateTeks = 'date';    // <-- I want to change this value
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(dateTeks),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      DateTime? _definedDate;    // <-- date value should saved in this variable from datePicker

                      await showModalBottomSheet(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) => Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .5,
                          child: Column(children: [
                            TextButton(           // <-- the button shouldn't be moved down
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    dateTeks = _definedDate!.toIso8601String();
                                    // set the text with date value
                                  });
                                },
                                child: Text('filter')),
                            filterBox(definedDate: _definedDate)
                          ]),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text('show snackbar'))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget filterBox({
    DateTime? definedDate
  }) {
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) => Wrap(
        spacing: 10,
        runSpacing: 10,
        children: [
          pickDate(definedDate),   // <-- the datePicker
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget pickDate(DateTime? tgl) {
    if (tgl == null) {
      tgl = DateTime.now();
    }
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) => InkWell(
          onTap: () async {
            final DateTime? _pickedTgl = await showDatePicker(
                context: context,
                initialDate: tgl!,
                firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 1),
                lastDate: tgl!,
                initialEntryMode: DatePickerEntryMode.calendarOnly,
                currentDate: DateTime.now());
            if (_pickedTgl != null && _pickedTgl != tgl) {
              setState(() {
                tgl = _pickedTgl;
                // the value from _pickedTgl is assigned to tgl, but it wont setted to
                // definedDate
              });
            }
          },
          child: Text(tgl!.toIso8601String())),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't set variables inside other functions like that. It will just overwrite the local variable that is the argument of that function

Comment: so how should I do it? based on code structure,

Comment: I'll write an answer, give me a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign variables like that. Consider this code.

```
void main() {
   String s = 'A';
   changeString(s);
   print(s);
}

void changeString(String p) {
   p = 'B';
}
```

The `s` in the main function won't be changed, because the `p` in the `changeString` function is its own local variable. While it will refer to the same object they are different variables meaning that assignment to it won't change the other. This is also happening in your code. To solve your problem I would lift the `_definedDate` completely out of the function and refer to it directly. This is the solution with minimal changes:

```
class Takok extends StatefulWidget {
  const Takok({super.key});

  @override
  State<Takok> createState() => _TakokState();
}

class _TakokState extends State<Takok> {
  String dateTeks = 'date';    // <-- I want to change this value
  DateTime? _definedDate;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(dateTeks),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () async {

                      await showModalBottomSheet(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) => Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .5,
                          child: Column(children: [
                            TextButton(           // <-- the button shouldn't be moved down
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    dateTeks = _definedDate!.toIso8601String();
                                    // set the text with date value
                                  });
                                },
                                child: Text('filter')),
                            filterBox()
                          ]),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text('show snackbar'))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget filterBox() {
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) => Wrap(
        spacing: 10,
        runSpacing: 10,
        children: [
          pickDate(),   // <-- the datePicker
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget pickDate() {
    if (_definedDate == null) {
      _definedDate = DateTime.now();
    }
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) => InkWell(
          onTap: () async {
            final DateTime? _pickedTgl = await showDatePicker(
                context: context,
                initialDate: _definedDate!,
                firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 1),
                lastDate: _definedDate!,
                initialEntryMode: DatePickerEntryMode.calendarOnly,
                currentDate: DateTime.now());
            if (_pickedTgl != null && _pickedTgl != _definedDate) {
              setState(() {
                _definedDate = _pickedTgl;
                // the vaue from _pickedTgl is assigned to tgl, but it wont setted to
                // definedDate
              });
            }
          },
          child: Text(_definedDate!.toIso8601String())),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT:
Not sure if this is the best way but here's a solution if you want 3 of them. You can try it and maybe adjust it to your needs:

```
class Takok extends StatefulWidget {
  const Takok({super.key});

  @override
  State<Takok> createState() => _TakokState();
}

class _TakokState extends State<Takok> {
  List<String> dateTeks = ['date', 'date', 'date'];
  List<DateTime?> _definedDate = [null, null, null];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(dateTeks[0]),
                Text(dateTeks[1]),
                Text(dateTeks[2]),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () async {

                      await showModalBottomSheet(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) => Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .5,
                          child: Column(children: [
                            ...test(0),
                            ...test(1),
                            ...test(2),
                          ]),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text('show snackbar'))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> test(int index) {
    return [
      TextButton(           // <-- the button shouldn't be moved down
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              dateTeks[index] = _definedDate[index]!.toIso8601String();
              // set the text with date value
            });
          },
          child: Text('filter')),
      filterBox(index)
    ];
  }

  Widget filterBox(int index) {
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) => Wrap(
        spacing: 10,
        runSpacing: 10,
        children: [
          pickDate(index),   // <-- the datePicker
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget pickDate(int index) {
    if (_definedDate[index] == null) {
      _definedDate[index] = DateTime.now();
    }
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) => InkWell(
          onTap: () async {
            final DateTime? _pickedTgl = await showDatePicker(
                context: context,
                initialDate: _definedDate[index]!,
                firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 1),
                lastDate: _definedDate[index]!,
                initialEntryMode: DatePickerEntryMode.calendarOnly,
                currentDate: DateTime.now());
            if (_pickedTgl != null && _pickedTgl != _definedDate) {
              setState(() {
                _definedDate[index] = _pickedTgl;
                // the vaue from _pickedTgl is assigned to tgl, but it wont setted to
                // definedDate
              });
            }
          },
          child: Text(_definedDate[index]!.toIso8601String())),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what if `pickDate()` is used 3 or more time, should I declare each DateTime variable?

Comment: how to make `pickDate()` reuseable for another date varibale?

Comment: should I make `pickDate()` as a _class_ ?

Comment: I don't really understand the use case, but maybe it could be better to separate it to a different class yes. It's hard for me to see what you eventually want to have

Comment: because, actually I have 3 date variable that I'm using for date filtering,2 for DateTimeRange and 1 for specific date

Comment: @pras i added to the answer a solution with 3. Not sure if this is what you need but maybe it can help you figure out the right solution

Comment: ah, yes, thank you, you've just give me insight